# CUDA External calls not supported

Tags: cuda

I am developing a CUDA 4.0 application running on a Fermi card. According to the specs, Fermi has Compute Capability 2.0 and therefore should support non-inlined function calls.

I compile every class I have with nvcc 4.0 in a distinct obj file. Then, I link them all with g++-4.4.

Consider the following code :

[File A.cuh]

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

struct A
{
    __device__ __host__ void functionA();
};
```

[File B.cuh]

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

struct B
{
    __device__ __host__ void functionB();
};
```

[File A.cu]

```
#include "A.cuh"
#include "B.cuh"

void A::functionA()
{
    B b;
    b.functionB();
}
```

Attempting to compile A.cu with `nvcc -o A.o -c A.cu -arch=sm_20` outputs `Error: External calls are not supported (found non-inlined call to _ZN1B9functionBEv)`.

I *must* be doing something wrong, but what ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained on [this thread on the NVidia forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=191164), it appears that even though Fermi supports non-inlined functions, nvcc still needs to have all the functions available during compilation, i.e. in the same source file: there is no linker (yep, that's a pity...).

Comment: One year later: As of CUDA 5.0, nvcc can now link device objects (`-dc` flag).

Answer (score 1):

`functionB` is not declared and therefore considered external call. As the error said external calls are not supported. Implement `functionB` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

True, CUDA 5.0 does it. I can't get it to expose external device variables but device methods work just fine. **Not by default.**

The nvcc option is "-rdc=true". In Visual Studio and Nsight it is an option in the project properties under Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common -> Generate Relocatable Device Code.