# CUDA and C++, how to link cpp and cu files?

Tags: c++, cuda

```
//Header file A.h
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
class A
{
   __host__ __device__ void move();
}

//cu file A.cu
#include "A.h"
{
   __host__ __device__ void A::move()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

When calling the method defined in the `A.cu` file from another `.cu` file, I`m getting the following error:

```
External calls are not supported (found non-inlined call to ...),
```

I'm using the `sm_10` compile option.

Comment: Does this post [CUDA External calls not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994005/cuda-external-calls-not-supported) already provide you with useful information?

Comment: after setting -rdc=true and srm_20 im getting:
Undefined reference to '_ZNmoveEv'

Comment: You cannot use compilation for compute capability `2.0` with relocatable code when you have a card with compute capability `1.0`...

Comment: i checked my card info and you are right, my card isnt support compute capability 2.0, thanks

Comment: @JackOLantern can you summarize the assistance you gave into an answer?  I would upvote it.

Comment: I presume A.cpp is actually A.cu. The host C++ compiler can't compile \_\_device\_\_ and \_\_host\_\_ decorators, only nvcc understands how to parse those.

Comment: @talonmies You are right. I have edited the post and fixed the misprint.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks Robert. I have added an answer.

Comment: A device method cannot be defined in a .cpp file unless specific compile behavior override switches are passed to nvcc. The posting is still unclear on this point.

Comment: this is a cpp file!.
if i implement the function in the header it work,
so why i cant implement the function in cpp?

Comment: nvcc takes (by default) .cpp files and hands them directly off to the host compiler (i.e. gcc, cl.exe, etc.)   The host compiler knows nothing about `__device__` and `__host__` and should emit a syntax error when you attempt to compile.  I'm simply repeating here the comment that @talonmies has already made above.  The easiest solution is to define your device functions in .cu files.

Comment: i guess my compiler is smarter then yours ;)
i left the implementation in the .h file and no syntax error,
it even run :),
thank you

Comment: Sure. A .h file included in a .cu file is fine. A .h file with device code included in a .cop file would ordinarily be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *separate compilation*. Separate compilation requires cards with compute capability at least `2.0` and at least CUDA 5.0.

Quoting the CUDA 5.0 Release Highlights:

> All `__device__` functions can now be separately compiled and linked using NVCC. 
>   This allows creation of closed-source static libraries of `__device__` functions and 
>   the ability for these libraries to call user-defined `__device__` callback functions. 
>   The linker support is considered to be a BETA feature in this release.

Separate compilation is described in Chapter 7 of the [CUDA COMPILER DRIVER NVCC Reference Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Compiler_Driver_NVCC.pdf).

For those interested, there is a very good thread on separate compilation in the NVIDIA forum, see

[How to create a static lib for device functions using cuda 5.0?](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/526645/how-to-create-a-static-lib-for-device-functions-using-cuda-5-0-/)