# External calls are not supported - CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

Objective is to call a device function available in another file, when i compile the **global** kernel it shows the following error ***External calls are not supported (found non-inlined call to _Z6GoldenSectionCUDA)***.

Problematic Code (not the full code but where the problem arises),
cat norm.h

```
# ifndef NORM_H_
# define NORM_H_
# include<stdio.h>

__device__ double invcdf(double prob, double mean, double stddev);

#endif
```

cat norm.cu

```
# include <norm.h>

__device__ double invcdf(double prob, double mean, double stddev) {
    return (mean + stddev*normcdfinv(prob));
       }
```

cat test.cu

```
# include <norm.h>
# include <curand.h>
# include <curand_kernel.h>

__global__ void phase2Kernel(double* out_profit, struct strategyHolder* strategy) {
       curandState seedValue;
       curand_init(threadIdx.x, 0, 0, &seedValue);
       double randomD = invcdf(curand_uniform_double( &seedValue ), 300, 80);
    }
```

nvcc -c norm.cu -o norm.o -I"."
nvcc -c test.cu -o test.o -I"."

Comment: Please post an example to reproduce the problem (see [here](http://sscce.org) for guidance), your code works for me.

Comment: In the real code (as opposed to what you have shown here), are you explicitly calling a constructor or are you relying on the default constructor of the class?

Comment: Could you please specify nvcc arguments that you use?

Comment: Posted the real code. I am using Makefile to compile, the command i used is  __nvcc -c file.cu -o file.o__

Comment: @Bala: The code you just posted compiles without error. Vote to close. If you can't provide code which reproduces the problem, we cannot help you.

Comment: What you just edited also compiles for me after I add the correct include for curand_kernel.h. Nothing I have tried can make any of the code you have posted fail to compile....  Are you really saying that if you cut and paste this code into a new file and compile it, that it fails with the error you say it does?

Comment: @Tom it compiles fine when i put all the functions in same file (say test.cu) but it throws the above error when i put them in different files (say kernel.cu, norm.h ) and include their headers to form final executable

Comment: @Bala I cannot figure out why putting part of the above code in a separate `.h` file and then including it in the `.cu` file should lead to compilation errors. Could you please edit your question with the exact file partition reproducing the error?

Comment: @Jack Added the exact code. Also tried compiling with -arch=sm_20 as suggested in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994005/cuda-external-calls-not-supported?rq=1) but no success

Comment: @Bala Your code still compiles fine to me. From your compilation line, you are not using the `-rdc=true` option to generate relocatable code. Please, note that you are in the separate compilation framework.

Comment: OK so now we have a *completely* different question than there was before...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to do separate compilation, which needs some special command line options. See the [NVCC manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) for details, but here's how to get your example to compile. I've targeted sm_20, but you can target sm_20 or later depending on what GPU you have. Separate compilation is not possible on older devices (sm_1x).

- You don't need to declare the `__device__` function as `extern` in your header file, but if you have any static device variables they will need to be declared as `extern`
- Generate relocatable code for the device by compiling as shown below (`-dc` is the device equivalent of `-c`, see the [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) for more information)

  ```
  nvcc -arch=sm_20 -dc norm.cu -o norm.o -I.
  nvcc -arch=sm_20 -dc test.cu -o test.o -I.
  ```
- Link the device parts of the code by calling nvlink before the final host link

  ```
  nvlink -arch=sm_20 norm.o test.o -o final.o
  ```

Comment: Is it necessary to declare the `__device__` function as `extern`? I'm compiling the above code with the `-rdc=true` option without `extern`. Is there perhaps something I don't see?

Comment: @Tom extern is not really needed i guess. It compiles fine with the directions pointed out in the link you have provided.

Comment: `extern` is definitely required for statically defined symbols to prevent duplication errors during linking, but a forward declaration should be sufficient for a function.

Comment: As talonmies said, you don't need `extern` on the function declaration, I was too hasty. I've modified the answer to reflect this for future visitors.